# Program for a 4x4 keypad calculator using assemply files as the operation functions. Mbed Using a nucleo f401re microcontroller

Tags: c++, mbed

Update: Sorry this is my first time posting. This the error I am getting in mbed

Fatal error: A1023E: File "../../build/mul_asm.NUCLEO_F401RE.E" could not be opened: No such file or directory
1 Error, 0 Warnings

from this block of code:

```
int perf_op(void)
{
    
    unsigned char key;
    int num1, num2, result;
    key = keypad_scan();
    
    if(key == 'A')
        result = add_asm(num1, num2);
    else if( key == 'B')
        result = sub_asm(num1,num2);
    else if(key == 'C')
        result = mul_asm(num1,num2);
    else if(key == 'D')
        result = sdiv_asm(num1,num2);
    else
        return 0xFF;
        
    return result;
}
```

It seems like it can't find the file in the directory, but it is in there and I have tripled checked the spelling and everything matches. Just wondering what other things could cause this error?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: *"I am trying to write a program that using mbed that [does at least six different things]*" -- please focus on **one** issue per question. Your [mre] should not need to cover *everything* your assignment does.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: *"I am getting an 'Expected unqualified-id' error.*" -- you are free to interpret your error message as long as you are able to provide a solution. If you ask someone else for help, you should provide the full error message, verbatim. You may need to format the error message as code, as many compilers rely on a fixed-width font to describe where the error occurs.